# OwnCloud 8: how to show raw text file in brownser instead of the download button?

Tags: browser, download, owncloud, textfiles, raw

The answer to my question has already been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/839083/how-to-show-file-in-browser-instead-of-downloading) by [@ceremcem](https://superuser.com/users/187576/ceremcem). However, in the meanwhile (the question is from 2014), OwnCloud has evolved and the URL structure has changed.

According to my researches, there still doesn't seem to be a off-the-shelf solution for it, and I was wondering if anyone knows which files to hack to show the full text inside the browser.

Thanks